# Run a custom function on a WordPress page

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, custom-fields

I have a function in my WordPress theme `functions.php` file with the following code:

```
function locations() {
    $locations_list = array();
    query_posts(array('orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC' , 'post_type' => 'location'));
    while(have_posts()) {
      $locations_list[the_slug()] = the_title();
    }
    wp_reset_query();
    return $locations_list;
}
```

The idea is that I can run this function anywhere on my site and it will store all my posts in an array.

However, I have no idea how I run this at the public end :'(

Perfect world, I'd like to run this in my `footer.php` script.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Perfect world, I'd like to run this in my footer.php script.

Then simply run the function in the footer.php template from your theme.

Also, avoid using `query_posts()` for custom queries because that function alters the main query. Use the [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class directly instead:

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(...));
while($query->have_posts()) {
  $query->the_post();
  // $locations...
}
```

FYI [`the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) prints the post title on the screen, so you don't need to assign it to a variable because it returns nothing.

Comment: I'll give it a whirl. Won't be a moment :-)